# Не работают кнопки

Tags: html, jquery

у меня есть парсер парсит строку с данным и есть на каждом кнопка, на кнопке у меня id="unban" и так на каждом, хочу нажать на 1 строку код работает если на 2+ то ничего не происходит, в консоль ничего не пишет.

Мой js jquery

```
$("#unban").click(function() {
alert("123");
});
```

Html кнопка

```
 <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-id='{$user['ID']}' data-login='{$user['Name']}' id='unban'>Разблокировать</button>
```

Comment: Если парсер ищет в строке, то какое отношение имеет к DOM элементам `id unban`? `click` присваивается уже к найнедым и загруженным элементам. В ином случае используется `$("#element").on('click', { ... })` - Который присваивает клик не к найденным элементам, а сперва ищет их. Смотрите логи в консоле браузера. Я понимаю что только сверхразумы дебажат через alert, но в консоли будет больше информации

Comment: Всё извиняюсь, забыл что можно использовать class в div